# Should I put a less impressive undergrad on my CV if I have two impressive Master's degrees?

Tags: resume

By ‘less impressive’, I mean that it was at a poorly ranked uni. Bottom half according to the national rankings. I still did well there academically and got a couple of awards.

By contrast, the two Master's are both from world-leading places.

I originally included all three, but a couple of acquaintances advised me to omit my first degree.

Comment: As with any other accomplishment or experience on your resume, list it if you feel it adds value appropriate to the amount of space it takes up and omitting it would raise questions you don't really want raised (like what you were doing during that time or why you didn't include it).

Comment: How is this off-topic? I don't understand.

Comment: If the degree is relevant to the job you should list it, if it’s not relevant then you shouldn’t list it, if asked about it you should be truthful with your response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I spend about 10% of my workday reviewing resumes and sorting them in "yes", "no", "strong yes", "definitely not" piles. So, I've seen quite a lot of resumes.

One of the things that annoys me is when the bachelor's degree is not listed. So, not listing it contributes to a less favourable impression. Why? Well, I want to see:

- What environment the candidate was in.
- What tech exposure they got.
- Which professors or professionals in my network might have an opinion about the candidate, the program, or the university.
- What is the overall career path of the candidate. Where are they coming from, where are they going.
- Does it all hold up together or is this another embellished/fabricated résumé
- Which courses/experience the candidate likely had. We'll use it to select the tech questions and the use case scenarios we present.

You should include all university degrees.

Comment: I'm also confused by the downvotes...

Comment: I don't get the downvotes either.

Comment: FWIW, I like resumes that list hobbies. Makes it easier to assess cultural fit.

Comment: I am on the fence for downvoting, mainly because of the `<rant/>` part: You seem to think everythin should be as you wish it to be. I am sorry to inform you, but the world doesn't revolve around a (seemingly) US-centric workplace. For example, in my location it is totally normal and expected to include a picture (and thereby and by your name your gender in almost all cases) with your CV. Also, the downvotes might be from people liking pottery as you just labeled their hobby "pointless".

Comment: I have upvoted the answer, but I'd downvote the rant part. It's good advice, but at the wrong place. I had to think for a second before voting. I'm sure most downvotes are for the rant.

Comment: @maxathousand This is due to an edit at a later point in time. When I wrote my comment it was still pointless (see edit history).

Comment: @dirkk Ah, my apologies.

Comment: @dirkk I sort of agree with you but mentioning gender and a photo is just entrenching gender and racial bias - the eu should have banned pics with CV's decades ago

Comment: @Neuromancer I agree regarding the policy. But we have to live with what we got, even if we want a policy change. My point was not that I agree with this particular thing, but a line of thought I often see on workplace.se: That everything is focuses on US workplace issues/cultures/resumes, whereas all SE have a diverse user base and especially workplace customs are quite different in different countries.

Answer (score 19):

List it, if nothing else it shows progression, same as anything else on a resume.  Going from "generic university" to "Big Name School" shows that you must have done well to pull off a change like that.

Comment: Thanks. That's kind of what I thought - if anything, it shows that I was able to overcome obstacles